# Using ffmpeg to convert a MOV file from a Nikon 3200D camera into a intermediate (mpegts) format - audio issue

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am using a command found on SO to convert from MOV to the intermediate format. The reason for this middle step is to be able to concatenate a series of MOV files.

For some reason, when I run the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mov -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts dest.ts
```

I lose the audio.

I tried adding `-bsf:s pcm_s16le` but that did not change an iota.

Here is the output

```
ffmpeg version N-74313-g9c0407e Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 30.100 / 54. 30.100
  libavcodec     56. 57.100 / 56. 57.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 32.100 /  5. 32.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'source.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537331968
    compatible_brands: qt  niko
    creation_time   : 2015-12-29 20:27:21
  Duration: 00:00:47.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 22117 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m/bt709/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 20535 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25
k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-12-29 20:27:21
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-12-29 20:27:21
File 'dest.ts' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mpegts, to 'dest.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537331968
    compatible_brands: qt  niko
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 20535 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-12-29 20:27:21
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-12-29 20:27:21
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1182 fps=1139 q=-1.0 Lsize=  137797kB time=00:00:47.28 bitrate=23875.6kbits/s
video:118525kB audio:8865kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.169999%
```

From the output, it does look like I copied both the video stream and the audio stream. So what seems to be the trouble?

Comment: How do you know you "lose the audio"?

Comment: Hmm. I have never tried using PCM in a TS. Would it be acceptable to encode the audio to aac, or mp3?

Comment: Yes encoding to mp3 is definitely possible... I lose the audio because I cannot hear it when I play it back or convert it further to mp4.

Comment: What does `ffprobe` say for `dest.ts`?